Are agricultural products and crops measured and compared by monetary value, mass, volume or calorie content?
This may seem a weird or stupid question (my first one Economics SE), but....
Most of the time in the media I see, hear or read about percentages, such as, "X-percent of food consumed worldwide is rice"; or, "Y-percent of the world's cocoa comes from Ghana", or, "soybean production has soared by Z-percent."......
Sources rarely say what unit or measure they are using... or if they take inflation into account... or changing, updated calorie counts for foodstuffs.... etc....
